# self.tabBarController.selectedIndex not calling viewDidAppear:YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In a tabbar view when I call the tab to load useing self.tabBarController.selectedIndex the viewWillAppear is not called If i am been to the tab before hand is there a way to force the view to reload.

self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController viewDidAppear:YES];

I was also thanking of dumping memory ever time i change tab's and that way when i get back to that view it reloads from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement

`- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

in the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` (probably your app delegate).  Then in there you can manually call the methods you want on whichever index's viewController you selected.

Comment: Ok i may have a problem setting a string instead. I make a file and save it to the hardware then use stringWithContentsOfFile to read the file to and NSString I am to use it in the next view but not the string is null if i open this file with the auto select. If i change tabs and then go back to the one i want to load i get my data.                              NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];